# Birthday Paradox's probability coming out to be zero,also not understanding how to use simulations

Tags: java, random

I have been trying to create a program which calculates the probability of 2 people's birthday being the same, considering there are 23 people in the room

I have made logic but the probability always comes out to be zero, it should be above 0.5,this is my first computer science class so i am not too familiar with java and coding.

I saw some programs online with multiple simulations, but i was not able to understand it.

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static int rand_bd() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int x = rand.nextInt(365);
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        
        int h = 0;
        double count = 0.0;
        int g = rand_bd();

        for(int i = 0;i  <= 23;i++) {
            h = rand_bd();
            if(g == h)
                count++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        System.out.println(count/23.0);
        System.out.println(rand_bd());
    }
}
```

Comment: @QBrute it isn't calculating that.

Comment: Your code indicates you misunderstand the problem. You randomly pick a day of the year (DOY). Then, you make 23 attempts to randomly find a DOY that matches that one. That's *not* the birthday paradox. You want to generate 23 random DOYs. For each DOY generated, you want to find if **any** of the other DOYs match.

Comment: You are taking a single person `g` and checking whether someone else shares their birthday. You need to read through the birthday paradox and understand what it is.

Comment: Isn't the probability always _1 in (365 * 23)_, or _1 in 8395_,  or _0.00012_?

Comment: @Reilas No. Assuming birthdays are independent and uniformly distributed, and ignoring leap years, the probability of a duplicate amongst *k* people is P{duplicate|*k*} = 1 - P{no duplicates|*k*} = 1 - Product(from_i=: 1, to: *k*, (366-i)/365}. In Ruby it's a one-liner: `1.0 - (1..k).inject { |memo, i| memo * (366.0 - i) / 365.0 }`. This yields P{duplicate|1} = 0 (makes sense!); P{duplicate|2} = 0.002739726027397249 = 1/365 (also makes sense); ...; P{duplicate|22} = 0.4756953076625502; P{duplicate|23} = 0.5072972343239855. By the time you get up to 60, P{duplicate} > 0.99 — a great bar bet.

Comment: @pjs, wow!  Now I remember why I failed algebra.  That's very interesting, thanks for the inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

**Preliminary remark:**

You seem to be using one `Random` generator object per random value (in your `rand_bd` method). But this is not how pseudo-random number generation is supposed to work, and so you are in untested circumstances.

The only thing that gets (very extensively) tested by library designers is that the serie produced by a *single* `Random` object has the proper statistical properties. So you should modify your code to ensure that a single `Random` object is used throughout a whole simulation, typically by passing (the address of) your single generator object to `rand_bd`.

**The main issue:**

You seem to be testing each new random value for equality with the very first random value only. But, as mentioned in the comments, this is not how the [Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) is supposed to work.

Each new pseudo-random value has to be tested for equality with **all** previous values.

In order to test for all previous values, rather than writing low level Java code we can just maintain and use an `HashSet<Integer>` object that is to contain all previously found pseudo-random values.

This can be done for example with the following code:

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.Random;

public class SO_q77456187  {

    public static int rand_bd(Random rand) {
        int x = rand.nextInt(365);
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");

        Random rand      = new Random();
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

        int h = 0;
        int classSize = 23;
        double count = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i  < classSize; i++) {
            h = new Integer(rand_bd(rand));
            if (set.contains(h))
                count++;  // collision found !
            else
                set.add(h);
        }
        if (count > 0)
            System.out.println("collision");
        System.out.println(count);
        System.out.println(count / Double.valueOf(classSize));
        System.out.println(rand_bd(rand));
    }
}
```

And as expected, the class file generated by the above code finds one or more collisions about 50% of the time.

Comment: BTW `HashSet.add()` returns a boolean indicating if the set did not contain the element, no need to check `contains()`

Comment: Your program doesn't estimate the probability of collisions. It seems to be estimating the proportion of students who were involved in a collision in a single replication of the scenario.

Comment: @pjs You're right, it doesn't. In order to minimize changes to the OP code, I relied on an external Bash shell script loop to run my test 10000 times. Something like: `k=10000; time (while [ $k -gt 0 ]; do   java SO_q77456187;   k=$(expr $k - 1); done) > log.txt` . And finally: `grep -c collision  log.txt` . Found 5139 runs out of 10000 with at least one collision.

Comment: Nice work, @jpmarinier.  In _Java_, the _Double_ and _double_ are, for the most part, interchangeable.  Meaning, _h = rand_bd(rand)_, would work, as well as, _count / classSize_.  Here is the _Java_ tutorial regarding this process, _[Autoboxing and Unboxing (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Numbers and Strings)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)_.

Comment: @Reilas - Thanks for the info ! I have to admit that, while having some grasp of random number generation, I am only an occasional user of Java.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me reiterate jpmarinier's comment that you should only create one `Random` object. Instantiating a new one for each value to be generated is expensive, and it negates all of the hard work that the PRNG creators did to insure that sequences of values properly mimic independent uniformly distributed values.

Next, I think you've missed the essence of the birthday problem. It asks what is the probability of having one *or more* duplicate birthdays among a set containing some specified number of people. It's a boolean choice, there either are duplicates or there are not. As soon as you find one duplicate, you can short-circuit the checking process since the goal is not to count how many occurred. This is easy to do using `Set` objects, which don't permit duplicates.

Finally, you're missing the essence of [Monte Carlo simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method), which is that you need replication of a randomized experiment. Since the outcome of a single experiment is a random event (duplicates/no-duplicates), you get better estimates of the probability of that event by running lots of experiments. Lots and lots. Additionally, since re-running random experiments gives different outcomes, it's nice to know the "margin of error" for whatever you're estimating. This comes in the form of what's called a confidence interval half-width.

The following code pulls those pieces together:

```java
import java.util.HashSet; 
import java.util.Random;

public class BdayMonteCarlo {
    // only create one instance of Random per program!
    private static Random rng = new Random();

    /*
     * Each experiment places classSize students in the room, checking
     * to see if there are any collisions on the birth dates.
     */
    public static int experiment(int classSize) {
        // each experiment starts with an empty set of birthdays
        HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

        // for each student, generate a birthday and try adding it to set
        // if add fails, short circuit and signal a collision
        for (int i = 0; i  < classSize; i++) {
            if(!set.add(rng.nextInt(365)))
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;   // if all people in class missed collisions, signal no collision
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int classSize = 23;
        int numberOfExptsWithCollisions = 0;
        int numberOfExperiments = 100_000;

        // Monte Carlo replication of the experiment, tallying results
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfExperiments; ++i) {
            numberOfExptsWithCollisions += experiment(classSize);
        }

        // probabilities are estimated using proportions of outcomes
        // that yielded a "success"
        System.out.print("Probability of one or more duplicate birthdays ");
        System.out.println("with classSize = " + classSize + " is:");
        Double prob = Double.valueOf(numberOfExptsWithCollisions) / numberOfExperiments;
        // confidence interval half-width for the estimate of a proportion/probability
        Double halfWidth = 1.96 * Math.sqrt(prob * (1.0 - prob) / numberOfExperiments);
        System.out.println(prob + " ± " + halfWidth);
    }
}
```

and produces results such as:

```text
me@mymachine % java BdayMonteCarlo      
Probability of one or more duplicate birthdays with classSize = 23 is:
0.5085 ± 0.0030985842644665968
me@mymachine % java BdayMonteCarlo
Probability of one or more duplicate birthdays with classSize = 23 is:
0.50936 ± 0.003098489049457235
```

You can clearly see that the proportion of experiments which had at least one duplicate birthday is above 0.5 for 23 people.